# Add references to a word document using java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to create a word document using JAVA where in there are dynamic references. How can I achieve that.

Like suppose I want to insert a picture from a URL say www.abc.com/1.jpg which is currently having a pciture of a snake. So I should see a snake in my doc. After some time the same URL points to some other image like that of an elephant. My doc should automatically show elephant when opened without any changes.

How can this be done using JAVA. Any working example would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Anshul

Answer (score 1):

I think that mostly depends whether you want the document to open in java or not.
If you want it that way you can parse the document, then while going through your objects in your document, find those URL references, download the images (neither by an API or implement your own API) and present it to the user.
I can't think of other way of making that happen.